# But total power dissipated in the two resistors in 3W. Where has the balance (rest) power 3W gone?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

Question 2: In the network of fig-2 shown in below. If you calculate and then get power supply by the battery 12V 6W. But total power dissipated in the two resistors in 3W. 
Where has the balance (rest) power 3W gone? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 12V battery is pushing current through the 6V battery in reverse i.e. from the cathode to the anode, so it is doing work by pushing the electrons against the electric field of the 6V battery.

If the batteries are rechargeable the 12V battery will be recharging the 6V battery. In that case half the power supplied by the 12V battery is dissipated as heat in the two resistors and half goes into charging the 6V battery.

If the 6V battery isn't rechargeable the power is just lost as heat in the 6V battery.